# Virtual Piano black keys offset

Tags: piano, keyboard

This is quite off-topic to some extent but I think it's still the right place to ask.

I am working on a new app and I want to implement an octave of piano keys in there. Unfortunately, in order to save space, I can't put the black keys in between the white ones, I need them to be aligned (unlike on a real piano). Now, I can't decide between letting them start on the C, or the D.

my preferred way would be to let the black keys start above the C 
[image: preferred]

the other possibilities would be to let it start on the D
[image: other]

What would you consider to be more "playable"? Please ignore the rest of the picture, I just used the app screenshot for demonstration. Also, do you think it is ok to place the black keys like that? Could you work with that?

Thanks, Alex

EDIT: I now played with both layouts for a couple of minutes and actually I got on with them way better than I thought. However, I now found another way to switch octaves (which is what I needed the space for) and will go for the "original" layout

UPDATE: Thanks a lot for everyone replying and making me rethink the layout. I now sacrificed a bit of the functionality and went for this:[image: final]

Answer (score 4):

Both are very unintuitive and kind of confusing. Why can't you put them in the middle, like in the Roland TB 3?

[image: ROland TB 3]

They occupy the same space as in your setup, but the positioning makes more sense and is more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like [image: this]

But, really, a pc keyboard has no key velocity and is often limited to 3 keys down max before it starts ignoring keys...  bleh :(

Answer (score 0):

Both are unintuitive and ambiguous, but if I had to choose, I would go with the second for two reasons:

1. Fingering with the right hand works a little bit better for chromatic scales, as well as flat keys (but the opposite is true for sharp keys and the left hand -- I'm considering that the right hand will be used more often).
2. It visually looks more like a piano keyboard to have space on either side of the black keys.

But really if at all possible, you should go with JCPedroza's suggestion.

Comment: I now played with both layouts for a couple of minutes and actually I got on with them way better than I thought. However, I now found another way to switch octaves (which is what I needed the space for) and will go for the "original" layout, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the fact that a keyboard player would hate it no matter what, from a *logical* standpoint neither can make sense, and for a reason: it would depend whether, in context, the black keys would be **sharps or flats**.

I suppose you'll have to go with @JCPedroza's suggestion.